# NSData contentsOfURL returns nil even though url is valid swift 2.0

Tags: swift, nsdata, youtube-data-api

There are other "NSData contentsOfURL returns nil" posts on here but none solve my issue.

I'm trying to get a profile image from YouTube via their APIv3.

```
//To get the images URL if hover over defaultProfileImageURL it shows it has a significant number of bytes not nil.

    let defaultProfileImageURL =  NSURL(string: "https://i.ytimg.com/i/cRfrPfLqP5kjfEcoNwC7_A/1.jpg")!

        //however defaultProfileImageData is nil even though defaultProfileImageURL has data when converted to NSData. 

    let defaultProfileImageData = NSData(contentsOfURL: defaultProfileImageURL) 

    let defaultProfileImage = UIImage(data: defaultProfileImageData!)
```

Why is it saying its nil when it shouldn't be?

Comment: the image link doesnt work

Comment: Yeah it does. I just checked 

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible reasons. First of there is no such Class method on the NSData Class. NSDictionary has this method in Swift, but not NSData. As far I see there are no convenience class methods for swift. You need to create and initialize a NSData object.

```
init(contentsOfURL url: NSURL,
           options readOptionsMask: NSDataReadingOptions) throws
```

seems the best option. You can check in throws what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let urlString = "http://herbadmother.com/wp-content/themes/thesis_18/custom/rotator/sample-1.jpg"
let imgURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            let defaultProfileImageData = NSData(data: data!)

            let defaultProfileImage = UIImage(data: defaultProfileImageData)

            // Do something with your image like: self.imageView.image = defaultProfileImage
        }
        task.resume()
```

Before running the code, add this to just after the first `<dict>` (because of Apple's security measures in iOS9):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>herbadmother.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Change `herbadmother.com` with your domain name.

Comment: Just wait a few seconds to load data.